# AWS Pinpoint Email Delivery Issues: 0 Messages Delivered Out of 9444 Sent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm facing an issue with AWS Pinpoint where my emails aren't being delivered, and I'm seeking insights or solutions. Here are the details:

- **Delivery count metrics:**

  - Messages sent: 9,444
  - Messages delivered: 0
  - Links clicked: 0
- **Account Details:**

  - Account tier: Production
  - Channel status: Enabled
  - Total messages sent: 16,870 (with a 50,000 message limit)

[image]

[image]

Despite the channel being enabled and under the message limit, none of the sent emails are getting delivered. I've checked for common issues like email formatting and sender address verification. Is there something I'm missing, or could there be a problem with AWS Pinpoint itself?

Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by directly contacting AWS support. The issue was an incorrect placeholder in the email, which prevented it from being sent. There's no way to detect this during the sending process, except by using CloudWatch and checking the "RenderingFailure" metric.
Bye!